# Making the site "longer"

Tags: html, css, web

I'm working on a site and I've got a piece of text on the side which doesn't fit completely, so part of it is not visible because the bottom of the site ends there. I want to make it scrollable so I can see the full content by scrolling down.

```css
#header {
 z-index: 1;
 position: fixed;
 width: 99%;
 margin-top: -20px;
 height: 800px;
 background-color: white;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 10px 16px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

#title {
 color: #03A9F4;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#content {
 display: flex;
}

#left {
 flex: 1;
}

#right {
 width: 200px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

#column {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 position:
}
 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #03A9F4;
}

#image1 {
 width:800px;
 height:400px;
 margin-left: 60px;
}
/*#03A9F4*/
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<html>
 <head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  <title>Future Tech network</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
 </head>
 
 <body bgcolor="#ECEFF1">
  <div id="header">
  <p id="title" align="center">Future Tech Network logo</p>
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Artikelen</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <img src="slogan.jpg" align="right">
</ul>

<div id="balk2"></div>
  
  <div id="content">
   <div id="left"><img id="image1" src="msi nightblade front.jpg" alt="Klik hier voor het volledige review"></div>
   <div id="right" align="center">
    <p id="column">Zoekend in de bakken van een tweedehands markt viel mijn oog op Quake II.
    Een meester titel van zijn tijd.
    Een tijd ver voor mijn tijd.
    Geïntegreerd door de plaatjes die grapics laten zien waar flash spelletjes niet aan kunnen tippen.
    Terwijl ik naar huis ga blijf ik kijken op de achterkant van het hoesje.
    Zoals ik dat ook altijd deed toen ik Rollercoaster tycoon kocht en Steam mij nog onbekend was. Het heeft toch wat.
    De fysieke kopie van een game. Om zo’n stukje klassieke game geschiedenis te vinden en het mee naar huis te kunnen nemen.
    het leek me prachtig om een plaats af te laten staan in mijn collectie van de nieuwste games door zo'n oude veteraan 
    Een mix van modern en klassiek. 
    Ik haalde de cd uit het hoesje maar tot mijn schrik miste er een diskdrive. Ik had die een paar maanden geleden trots ingewisseld voor een fan met de gedachte: “Ach alles staat toch op Steam”.
    Hier was hij dus. De tijd, hij heeft me ingehaald. Ik dacht hem te slim af te zijn door een stukje geschiedenis te kunnen spelen maar tijd haalt je altijd in.
    Nu is het niet meer dan een relikwie in een museum. Met een zucht start ik Steam op en geef ik me over aan de digitale economie van games</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

correct me if there are any more mistakes. im quite a noob so far but im trying to make the best of it.

Answer (score 0):

In most situations, when you know exactly how big the site must be, you can just set the body height:

```
body{
  height: 600px;
}
```

Sometimes you want the site to grow automatically + some extra pixels because for example, a footer which has position: fixed

```
footer {
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

In that scenario you can do:

```
body {
  padding-bottom: 100px
}
```

That way the body will a little more padding space so that the fixed footer don't obstruct the body content. I hope this helps.

Comment: Don't you need a `;` at the end of `padding-bottom: 100px`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using overflow-y: scroll;

```
<div id="right" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
```

Pls let me know if that helped

Comment: sorry man. it didnt. it created a scrollbar inside of the div. its its a not usable scrollbar